# Raster band values affecting analysis in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, clip, band

I've been trying to clip a raster data but the output each time has different band values resulting in different symbology.

I checked online and it seems there is no applicable solution, and I even saw some Youtube videos where such output was used as it was.

I'm new to this and I don't want to proceed with my analysis to later find out the difference in the band values has tampered with the results.

Is a clipped raster output any different from the parent raster file of different band values using ArcMap?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In ArcGIS for Desktop you can trick the renderer by copying the statistics of the larger raster, to do so:

1. Export the statistics of the raster you're trying to match to an XML file [Instructions](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009t00000207000000)
2. Set the properties of the raster using [Set Raster Properties](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000015z000000) or by the properties dialog of the raster.

Take these 4 1 km tiles for example, each will load with the correct statistics for the file which will be different to adjacent tiles so you can clearly see the tile edges:

[image: Before copying statistics]

After copying the statistics from one file to the 3 others:

[image: After copying statistics]

This trick should work with ArcGIS Pro.